# What is the difference between elliptical Gaussian and multivariate Gaussian distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, copula

I am reading about Metaelliptical copulas but I don't know the difference between elliptical Gaussian and multivariate Gaussian distributions I would appreciate if somebody can explain the difference in a simple way.
This is the paper that I was reading in case if you need more clarification.
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2006WR005275/abstract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference --
all multivariate Gaussian distributions are necessarily elliptical.

However, not all elliptical distributions are Gaussian.

As the article you point to says "... the well-known family of elliptical distributions, [...] is itself an extension of the classical multivariate normal distribution".